# Google Play Integrity API - LICENSED even when app is not from Google Play, but was before

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-integrity-api

We are integrating Google Play Integrity API into our app and during testing we found out that it behaves quite strange. It looks like it has some memory.

On device A has been app installed from Google Play, later uninstalled and installed new version for test environment from AppCenter (same appId, different signature) and Play Integrity says LICENSED (which is not true!).

On device B has been installed only new test version from AppCenter and Play Integrity says UNEVALUATED (which is true).

We haven't tested yet third option - after uninstalling test version from device B try version from Google Play. I guess, the result would be UNEVALUATED (false!).

There is not so much info in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#account-details-field) so I don't know whether is this behaviour bug or feature. Does anybody know more details? Thank you